# Where does "inaugural" go in this sentence?

Tags: structure, grammar, business-writing, clarity

I’ve been trying to adjust my short bio/blurb on LinkedIn to include the word “inaugural” in it, but, as soon as I do, it makes everything feel off and I'm not sure why. Here's what I've written (details changed for anonymity):

> Graphic designer and 2019 inaugural graduate of the Honours Bachelor of Graphic Design program from Harvard University.

Am I just imagining things, or does something sound wrong here? Should "inaugural" go before or after the year? Am I missing a comma somewhere? It almost feels as though the sentence is too jumbled.

Here's an alternate structure:

> Graphic designer and inaugural graduate of Harvard University’s 2019 Honours Bachelor of Graphic Design program.

To me, this reads better, but I don't like it for several reasons. It draws more attention to the school, which I dislike (I didn't actually go to Harvard, unfortunately). Also, it seems somewhat strange to be referring to it as the 2019 program even though it exists in years besides 2019.

Is there perhaps another structure which may make more sense than these two?

Answer (score 1):

Either works, but I think what you might be going for is:

> Graphic designer and inaugural graduate in 2019 of the Honours Bachelor of Graphic Design program from Harvard University.

or perhaps

> Graphic designer and inaugural graduate (2019) of the Honours Bachelor of Graphic Design program from Harvard University.